# Can gridlayout do it?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridlayout

I'm very weak in `GridLayout`, normally what I do is I'm using `LinearLayout` to do my interface but today I wish to try out the `Gridlayout`.

I'm been studying the `Gridlayout` for some times, just don't get it, don't understand the logic behind.

[image]

I wish to create a simple `Gridlayout` to store my object as below, can someone show me how to do it?

or may be `Gridlayout` cant do it???

Comment: is that a row layout in your sketch? try using a custom list view.

Comment: I think LinenearLayout would be easier for you to do this.

Comment: Answer is : **No** you can not do this with a GridLayout..!!

Comment: #Razgriz : yes that is my sketch
#Huy N : Yes, i manage to do it with using LinearLayout
#janki gadhiya : Are you sure is NO!? so far i also fail to build it with GridLayout.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 3):

maybe you can do it this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="TEXTT"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

If this is not what you are looking for just say, so I can try help you :)

Comment: Why the first LinearLayout? It's useless.

Comment: my bad, forget to remove it, I was testing all components to check if I could do it
I will delete it, tnx for saying :)

Comment: actually i'm able to build it with linearlayout, just i want to try to build the same interface with GRidLayout, see is workable or not...

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ff5110a09947da1b2435d4b976b4105a

Is this better? :)

Hope this can help you

Comment: thanks Fransico, but your sample is not showing right on my virtual device.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout>
  <ImageButton id="@+id/img1" 
    alignParentTop="true"
    alignparentLeft="true" />
  <ImageButton layout_below="@id/img1"
    alignparentLeft="true" />
  <TextView alignParentRight="true"
    alignParentTop="true" />
  <ImageView alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

You need to adjust width&height to fit your requirements

Comment: You asked if it was possible, it's not, here's the solution, as @Francisco Melicia said